# Python: graph redundant nodes (without Networkx)

Tags: python, graph, nodes, redundancy

We've been given standard beginner's python problem as a homework exercise, but my research into it shows people always use Networkx to solve these graph type node problems, whereas we're not allowed to use the Networkx built-in to solve it. I'm hoping for advice on a nice way to tackle this please.

There are five nodes (named 1,2,3,4,5) and the order is this:

- 1 goes nowhere
- 2 only goes to 1
- 3 goes to 1 and 5 (but 5 is closer which makes the 3 to 1 path redundant)
- 4 goes to 1 and 2 (but 2 is closer so 4-1 is redundant)
- 5 goes to 2

This is the example data to read in (note this is just one data set - it has to work with other pairs too):

```
['R(3,5)', 'R(4,2)', 'R(5,2)', 'R(2,1)', 'R(3,1)', 'R(4,1)']
```

This is the non-redundant pair output:

```
['R(3,5)', 'R(4,2)', 'R(5,2)', 'R(2,1)']
```

My attempt so far has been to split into two lists for start node and end node:

```
start_value = []
end_value = []
for i in range(len(partial_order)):
    start_value.append(int(partial_order[i][2]))
for i in range(len(partial_order)):    
    end_value.append(int(partial_order[i][4]))
dictionary = dict(zip(start_value, end_value))
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
{3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 2: 1}
```

I thought if I put it into a dictionary, I can try something from there, but my dictionary only shows 3:1 instead of 3:[1,5]. It is the 3-5 pair that I need to keep since it is closer, so 3-1 is redundant. Thanks for any tips on how to progress without Networkx.

This is one of pages I was reading - I'm trying to set up graph dictionary like that so I can try out their find_shortest_path function, to see if that gives me a solution.
https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

UPDATE:
I ended up abandoning the dictionary idea and zipping the two lists together then performed a whole bunch of if statements to get it working.

But I really would like to hear anyone's solution for something more Pythonic (so long as it doesn't use packages like Networkx). Happy coding.

Comment: Just thought I'd take the time to say you've put forth a good question in a good format. You've clearly shown the issue, presented your code and a test case, and laid out the requirements. Not many beginners do this, so thanks! You've got an upvote from me.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I'm an older dog trying to learn new tricks at university.

Comment: Could you explain more about the desired output? Should it be `{3: [1, 5], 4: [2, 1], 5: [2], 2: [1]}`? And what do "closer" and "redundant" mean?

Comment: ['R(3,5)', 'R(4,2)', 'R(5,2)', 'R(2,1)']

Comment: The final output should look like this: ['R(3,5)', 'R(4,2)', 'R(5,2)', 'R(2,1)'] The reason why path R(3,5) is kept and not R(3,1) is because 3 is closer to 5, which makes path 3,1 redundant (as a person would always choose to take the closer path and not walk the long way around to get from 3 to 1. So they'd take short trips from 3 to 5 to 2 to 1, which is closer than 3 to 1 directly.

Comment: From what I've read about it, it is a directed acyclic graph, since no node can point to itself and the arrows only point in one direction (so if it is 3,5, it will never go back from 5,3). But all the solutions I've seen use Networkx for directed acyclic graphs, which I'm not allowed to use.

Comment: How can we see from the data that R(3,1) is redundant?  It is not clear for me from the first list you present.

Comment: Right here in the instructions I pasted in the question: 3 goes to 1 and 5 (but 5 is closer which makes the 3 to 1 path redundant). I felt the instructions he's given us were pretty clear. I was able to solve it based on what he's written.